# Is it possible to send HTTPS posts in Delphi using Indy?

Tags: delphi, post, https, indy, idhttp

Is it possible to do https post requests in delphi? I tried a few tricks from the web to no avail. I have no experience in this area other than assembling a WSN using indy and delphi a few years ago (using tcp and udp binary packets).

```
mtxt:=TStringStream.Create('{some text here}',TEncoding.UTF8);
mhttp:=TIdHTTP.create(nil);
mIOHandler:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
mIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2,sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv23];
mIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvTLSv1_2; // no use of any other; firefox reports the site uses this one
mhttp.request.ContentType:='application/json';
mhttp.IOHandler:=mIOHandler;
mhttp.HandleRedirects:=true;
result:=mhttp.post('https://url here',mtxt);
```

Tidhttp is 10.6.something. Tried two sets of *eay32 DLL's from two sources. Varied a few more parameters than in the code above (probably irrelevant). All variations of the ssloptions.method produce errors, first three giving the same error message and the other two different ones. Unfortunately googling these messages leads to vain cries for help and/or fixes that don't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, of course. And the code you showed is *mostly* fine (but, DO NOT enable `sslvSSLv2` or `sslvSSLv23`, and DO NOT set `SSLOptions.Method` when using `SSLOptions.SSLVersions`), so whatever problem you are having (you didn't say what the errors are) will be due to either 1) using the wrong DLLs (you didn't say which ones you tried) or 2) some other factor we can't see from your limited information.

Comment: In addition to what Remy said, pay attention to deprecated SSL anf TLS versions. Don't use any SSL which are all deprecated. Use TLS 1.3 which is the latest or TLS 1.2. Also note that SLL/TLS versions and OpenSSL version are not the same. Currently we are at OpenSSL V3 which supports SSL 1.3.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i removed 2&23 from the versions line and the entire method line. Error is
EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL. error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure'. 
Dll's are either: 1.0.2 openssl shared library, dated 2018; or digitally signed by Zoom Video and Beijing Duodian Online. Which file should i download from the github openssl?
Prev. errors include
EidOSSLConnectError ... 00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib
EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError ... 14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: @fpiette sorry i lack knowledge of internet protocols to make use of your statement but i will keep it in mind of course, thx.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you must carefully select the value(s) you give to SSLOptions.SSLVersions in order to not select a deprecated SSL/TLS version. Deprecated means it has been cracked and is insecure.

Comment: @miodrag the highest OpenSSL version that `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` supports is 1.0.2u (note the u), which you can get from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries. It supports up to TLS 1.2. If you want to use TLS 1.3, use this (work-in-progress) SSLIOHandler instead: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299

Comment: I installed the u-label dll's and altered the code as you advised but nothing changed. According to firefox page info, the site uses TLS ESDCHE RSA WITH AES 128 GCM SHA256, 128 bit, TLS 1.2. Then i switched from 32-bit Windows to 64-bit Windows platform and the old error message was replaced with EIdHTTPProtocolException 'HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed'. Finally i downloaded the ICS package 8.67 from github but it requires studying how to compile and use.

Comment: If you are getting an HTTP protocol error on an HTTPS url then the TLS portion is working correctly. Are you sure the URL in question actually allows `POST` requests to begin with? Are you able to access the URL in question using a normal web browser? If so, then use the browser's built-in debugger to see the HTTP requests it is sending, and then you can replicate those requests with `TIdHTTP` (or any other HTTP client)

Comment: You're right. I used python and got 405 too. Something is wrong on their side. But still, dll's with the 32 suffix produced funny errors when i used delphi/win32. I will have more information when i fix the problem for good (i will know if the "funny" errors repeat under win32).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Does the *eay32.dll files in the x64_86-Win64 archive work with 64-bit Delphi? And should I use the ones from i386-win32 for 32-bit Delphi programs or the ones from x64_86-Win64 (I'm using latest 11.3 Delphi and Indy 10)?

Comment: Managed to get the connection working on 64-bit platform. No wonder since i extracted the files from the x64 archive, which i forgot, and was just fooled by the 32 suffix on the files themselves. So the answer to the question (which i may post,  or some of you guys) is that one needs to watch for platform and dll's version compatibility, among other things mentioned.